# French drain with Catch Basin

Tags: drainage, french-drain

I have a swale in the middle of my yard that is graded into city storm basin. Every time there is rain I get this swale area wet for days. I had the area graded, but still the problem comes back. I want to install French drain to fix the issue for good.

Below is the design of French drain with catch basin that I want to install. I want to run PVC pipe from catch basin and couple it to perforated drain pipe.

My question is what should be the transition between dirt surrounding PVC pipe and beginning of the French drain (marked in red line). My concern is that the dirt surrounding PVC pipe will eventually make its way into gravel surrounding French drain and contribute to its clogging. Should I add some kind of barrier between the two, like piece of nonwoven geotextile fabric? Should I do something else, or am I overthinking the whole thing?

**Additional Information**

I am located in North East where soil predominantly heavy clay. My plan for this is to dig a 16" trnech, layer it with 2" river rock, install runnonwoven geotextile fabric, put perforated pipe over in the fabric, dump more river rock over it, create burrito from the fabric and lastly cover with about 4" of topsoil and grass.

**Note**

While writing this post I read similar post where poster talks about clay clogging the French drain through the fabric, is that a concern that I should be worried about?
[image]

Comment: This question indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of what a swale is supposed to do.

Comment: The order of operations is to dig the trench, line it with geotextile, put down a bedding layer of gravel, lay your perforated pipe with a geotextile sock on the bedding, then backfill with more gravel to cover the pipe, and finally, wrap the geotextile lining on top of the gravel.  Then do your topsoil and grass.  Have you contacted the municipality to see if you can connect to their storm drain inlet?

Comment: A swale works to redirect a large amount of water, rapidly. We were worried about erosion in ours, so we lined it with man handable rocks. A perforated pipe solution will clog up slowly. It could take a decade or longer. It all depends.